# Why project template menue in my intelliJ does not contain Application option?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I am quite a beginner in kotlin. The book I am learning from shows that I must create an `Application` project using IntelliJ IDEA. But In contrast to the book instruction, the `Application` option does not exist under JVM heading in my project template menu. only  `Console Application` option there exists. what should I do?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The difference does not matter. Console Application includes a main.kt File containing a `main` function in advance, comparing to Application project. The link of the complete answer is here, thanks.
https://forums.bignerdranch.com/t/application-gone-from-jvm-choices-in-intellij-idea-2021-3/19547